# Reversing Order Scale - Math formulae help needed

Tags: google-sheets, math, spreadsheet, equation-solving

Can anyone help with a formula / equation to help with my problem?

I'm trying to do (reverse) the following..........

I know the Base Price to be 250
The no. of orders are 8
Each order increases at scale of 1.5

=250*(1.5^7) = 4271.48 total

Im trying (and failing) to come up with a formula to reverse the above equation to provide me with the the Base Price (assuming I now know the total, in addition to the no of orders and the scale)

i.e what formula would I use to get the Base Price, assuming I know know the total is 4271.48 (based on the same 8 orders and scale of 1.5)

I've attached a quick spreadsheet to help describe my problem!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hzHwvYbXWH8Pkpvf8K7GVyAFcgLWeRuTUcN9A1S52Hg/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Use `-` in power.

```
=B17*(1.5^-7)
```

Comment: @Simmo If it helps then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it).